# Fresh Lubuntu 20.04.5 - Continuous HDD I/O operations while in idle

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, noise, io

Freshly installed Lubuntu 20.04, with no software installed, HDD makes an abrupt sound every 2-5 seconds as if the disk is being read or written to momentarily (or possibly the head is attempting to park, or something like that).

I have one HDD with 4 partitions (boot,root,swap,home).

Here's my `iotop` output:

```
sudo iotop -o -t -d 10**
11:47:10     625 be/3 root  0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.94 % [jbd2/sda4-8]
11:47:10     281 be/3 root  0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.70 % [jbd2/sda1-8]
11:47:10    8954 be/4 root  0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % [kworker/u8:0-events_power_efficient]
11:47:10    9233 be/4 root  0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.02 % [kworker/u8:3-events_power_efficient]
```

The above output changes all the time, with some of the items included, some not, with the most frequent item probably being the kworker/u8.

Thing I've tried:

My HDD is a Western Digital Green Caviar. They have some in-built power management system. I tried disabling it (in suspicion of the head making the noise in an attempt to park) using the following two methods, one after the other - none of them worked (I did power-cycle the HDD, as recommended, that is I turned the power off/on for the changes to take effect):

```
sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda

sudo idle3ctl -s 138 /dev/sda
```

Any idea what's going on? The subtle but audible sound from the HDD every few seconds is simply driving me nuts, impossible to enjoy the lovely 20.04...

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's Lubuntu 20.04.5, since the current point release is 20.04.1

Comment: That's right, it's 20.04.1 - evidence that my drive is... driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find the processes that are accessing the file system is to use fnotifystat:

```
sudo apt install fnotifystat
sudo fnotifystat
```

There are normally I/Os occurring on pseudo file systems that can be excluded using:

```
sudo fnotifystat -x /sys,/proc
```

..finally one can classify the activity to the device using:

```
sudo fnotifystat -x /sys,/proc -D
```

Answer (score 0):

I have partly solved this problem.

I run **sudo fnotifystat** and I got the following, very frequent processes (they read the HDD every 1-5 seconds):

```
Total   Open  Close   Read  Write     PID  Process         Pathname
  3.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0      695 thermald        /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/energy_uj
  3.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0      695 thermald        /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/intel-rapl:0:2/energy_uj
  3.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0      695 thermald        /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp
  3.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    11650 lxqt-panel      /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Athens
  2.0    0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0     2583 xscreensaver    /proc/interrupts
```

The process thermald is to monitor the CPU temperature and prevent overheating, but is not a critical process, as well as people have reported problems with it, so I removed it and the corresponding processes stopped. I then also removed the screensaver package, which stopped the corresponding process.

The only process that remains - and keeps causing audible HDD nuisance every few seconds - is the calendar process that relates to zoneinfo (PID 11650), which other people have reported as a similar bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calendar/+bug/1846768 - in my case the I/O read cycle is even more frequent).